# How to test switch case in Junit using Mockito

Tags: java, junit, mockito, switch-statement

I am able to test the code but code coverage does not cover second switch case.

Please refer the below code.

```
 { @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager manager;

    @Autowired
    TurbineRepository turbineRepository;

    @Autowired
    WorkRepository workRepository;

    public Dropdown getDropdown(String type) {
        Dropdown dropdownDTO = new Dropdown();
        switch(type) {
        case "turbine":
            List<String> turbinesList = turbineRepository.listOfTurbines();
            dropdownDTO.setTurbinesList(turbinesList);
            break;
        case "wocreate":
            List<String> turbineList = turbineRepository.listOfTurbines();
            dropdownDTO.setTurbinesList(turbineList);
            List<ParamsProjection> params = workRepository.findBy();
            Map<String, List<ParamsProjection>> result = params.stream()
                    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(ParamsProjection::getType));
            dropdownDTO.setParams(result);
        default:
        }
        return dropdownDTO;

    }
```

Below is my test code.

```
{
    @InjectMocks
    private Services service;
    
    @Mock
    private WorkRepository workRepo;
    
    @Mock
    private TurbineRepository turbineRepo;
    
    @Mock
    private ParamsProjection paramProject1;
    
    @Test 
    public void getDropDown() {
        
        Dropdown dto = new Dropdown();
        List<String> turbineList = new ArrayList<String>();
        String type = "turbine";
        switch(type) {
        case "turbine" :
        Mockito.when(turbineRepo.listOfTurbines()).thenReturn(turbineList);
        dto.setTurbinesList(turbineList);
        assertNotNull(dto);
        break;
        
        case "wocreate": 
        DropdownDTO dto2 = new DropdownDTO();
        Mockito.when(turbineRepo.listOfTurbines()).thenReturn(turbineList);
        dto2.setTurbinesList(turbineList);
        List<ParamsProjection> param = new ArrayList<ParamsProjection>();
        Mockito.when(workRepo.findBy()).thenReturn(param);
        
        Map<String, List<ParamsProjection>> result = param.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(ParamsProjection::getType));
        
        dto2.setParams(result);
        assertNotNull(dto2);
        break;
}
        assertNotNull(service.getDropdown("turbine"));
}
```

As I have declared a string variable with value for testing , I am not able to cover the second switch statement.
I have tried if-else case but same problem occurs.
Is there any other way we can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `type` is always `"turbine"`, so just that case is tested. It would make sense to have two different tests, one for each type:

```java
@Test 
public void getDropDownTurbine() {
    
    Dropdown dto = new Dropdown();
    List<String> turbineList = new ArrayList<String>();
    String type = "turbine";
    Mockito.when(turbineRepo.listOfTurbines()).thenReturn(turbineList);
    dto.setTurbinesList(turbineList);
    assertNotNull(dto);
    assertNotNull(service.getDropdown("turbine"));
} 


@Test 
public void getDropDown() {
    
    List<String> turbineList = new ArrayList<String>();
    String type = "wocreate";
    DropdownDTO dto2 = new DropdownDTO();
    Mockito.when(turbineRepo.listOfTurbines()).thenReturn(turbineList);
    dto2.setTurbinesList(turbineList);
    List<ParamsProjection> param = new ArrayList<ParamsProjection>();
    Mockito.when(workRepo.findBy()).thenReturn(param);
    
    Map<String, List<ParamsProjection>> result = param.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(ParamsProjection::getType));
    
    dto2.setParams(result);
    assertNotNull(dto2);

    assertNotNull(service.getDropdown("wocreate"));
}
```

Comment: Thank you. It is working for two separate test cases...Is there any way to do it in a single test case?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of writing two different test cases you can simply use single parameterized test in which you can set different String value for each iteration.

```
`@ParameterizedTest
 @ValueSource(strings = {"value1", "value2"})
 void testMethod(String str) {
        //testLogic
 }`
```